# Deploying a react app on plesk obsidian issue

Tags: reactjs, plesk

I need help, if any one have experience with plesk obsidian

[image: image description here]

I deployed a react app on plesk and I have this error ,
I installed node-js on plesk and followed instructions but the same issue #react #help #deployment #deploy #deploying

Comment: You don’t need node to host react. Looks like you just copy pasted your react code. You need to build your code and the output is pure static content. Host it like any other static HTML site.

Comment: i built it and uploaded the zip file and it doesn't work